# Plotting coordinates from an algebraic operation

Tags: plotting, algebraic-manipulation

I have 30 algebraic operations which look like:

```
Clear[L];
L30 = 15 I;
R30 = Abs[-1/2*dU[3] + Abs[ud[3]]^2 - L*ud[3]]^{-1} - 
  Abs[-1/2*dU[-3] + Abs[ud[-3]]^2 - L*ud[-3]]^{-1}
```

When I  prepare these outputs of  R1, R2, ...,R30 into coordinate set for plotting I set up the set of coordinates:

spectrum={{L1, Log[R1]},....{L30, Log[R30]}}

However, this gives the unplottable format:

{{{Number1}, {Number2}},....{{Number3}, {Number4}}}

which is not plottable because it has extra curly brackets within the coordinate pair.

Instead, the output should be in the form

```
{{Number1, Number2},...,{Number3, Number4}}
```

in order to be plotted  using

```
yvals = Im@First@# & /@ spectrumq;
xvals = Abs@*Last /@ spectrumq;
ListLinePlot[SortBy[First][Transpose[{yvals, xvals}]], Mesh -> All]
```

where :

```
spectrumq = {{I, Log[R1]}, {-I, Log[R2]}, {-2 I, Log[R3]}, {2 I, 
   Log[R4]}, {3 I, Log[R5]}, {-3 I, Log[R6]}, {4 I, Log[R7]}, {-4 I, 
   Log[R8]}, {-5 I, Log[R9]}, {5 I, Log[R10]}, {6 I, Log[R11]}, {-6 I,
    Log[R12]}, {7 I, Log[R13]}, {-7 I, Log[R14]}, {8 I, 
   Log[R15]}, {-8 I, Log[R16]}, {9 I, Log[R17]}, {-9 I, 
   Log[R18]}, {10 I, Log[R19]}, {-10 I, Log[R20]}, {-11 I, 
   Log[R21]}, {11 I, Log[R22]}, {-12 I, Log[R23]}, {12 I, 
   Log[R24]}, {-13 I, Log[R25]}, {13 I, Log[R26]}, {14 I, 
   Log[R27]}, {-14 I, Log[R28]}, {-15 I, Log[R29]}, {15 I, Log[R30]}}
```

So this should ideally give a plot of all these points, but since the algebraic operation

```
Log[R12]
```

or any Log[R#]

outputs the double curly brackets, I cannot automatize that into a plotting command by just evaluating the entire notebook.

How can I change the coordinates for the plotting into usual points in the form  $(x_i, y_i)$, instead of the existing $(x_i, \{y_i\})$?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `{}` curly brackets in the exponent!

Comment: Thanks, I will change